# What were the Oriental influences on Heraclitus?

Tags: political-history, ancient-greece, philosophy

I'm reading Karl Popper's *The Open Society and its Enemies*. In chapter two, he mentions in passing that Greek philosophers such as Heraclitus were influenced by oriental ideas.
Is he referring to ideas from Mesopotamia and the Near East, or somewhere further such as China?

Comment: "Heraclitus (/ˌhɛrəˈklaɪtəs/; Greek: Ἡράκλειτος Herákleitos; fl. c. 500 BC)[1] was an ancient Greek pre-Socratic philosopher from the city of Ephesus, which was then part of the Persian Empire." [WIkipedia:Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus). Arguably, the Persian Empire is oriental

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: "Oriental" literally means "Eastern" (while "Occidental" means "Western"). The "Middle *East*", sometimes also known as the "Near East", is course just "East" with an adjective thrown on.